# iCloud Drive is always uploading and using resources

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, data-synchronization, mojave

My device is MacBook Pro 15" (mid 2017), macOS 10.14.3 with iCloud storage optimisation turned on and Desktop and Documents folders stored in iCloud.

Recently I noticed `bird` and `cloudd` processes using a lot of cpu, and iCloud always uploading some files, it really never stops.

I tried logging in and out of iCloud, turning synchronization on and off, but nothing seems to fix it. I've gone through all similar questions and corresponding answers with no luck.

How to stop that constant syncing and what can be the reason for it?

Comment: There's no question here.  Can you [edit] it and add your question?

Comment: @fsb, you're right, see my updated answer